# Using Definition of Derivative To Solve for Derivative

Tags: limits, derivatives

I am looking for any assistance with knowing where to start for the following two problems:

1. Consider the following equation:
   $$ f'(a) = \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+h) - f(a)}{h}$$

Let $ f(x) = \sqrt[3]{x} $

If a ≠ 0, use the above formula to find $ f'(a) $

2. Suppose f is a function which satisfies the properties:
   $$ f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y) + x^2y + xy^2 $$
   For all real numbers x and y, and
   $$ \lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x} = 1 $$
   Find $ f'(x) $

Comment: What have you tried already to solve these problems? Have you had any thoughts so far?

Comment: For question 1 I've tried: lim h->0 ((x + h)^1/3 - x^1/3)/h

I really haven't gotten far with either.

Comment: To "rationalize" the denominator in that first limit, you can use the formula for the difference of 2 cubes, $a^3-b^3 = (a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$

Comment: For the second one, why not setup the definition of derivative of $f(x)$ as a limit and let $y$ be $h$ in the identity.  See what's left.

Answer (score 1):

we have $$\frac{\sqrt[3]{x+h}-\sqrt[3]{x}}{h}=\frac{\sqrt[3]{x+h}-\sqrt[3]{x}}{h}\frac{\sqrt[3]{x+h}^2+\sqrt[3]{x+h}\sqrt[3]{x}+\sqrt[3]{x^2}}{\sqrt[3]{x+h}^2+\sqrt[3]{x+h}\sqrt[3]{x}+\sqrt[3]{x^2}}=...$$
can you proceed?

Answer (score 1):

For number 1 it is just a simple proof of power rule. You can derive it generally for $x^n$ by the binomial theorem. For number 2 we have $f'(x)=\displaystyle\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ by what the question tells us we know that this comes out to $\displaystyle\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac{f(x)+f(h)+x^2h+xh^2-f(x)}{h}$ $=\displaystyle\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac{f(h)}{h}+x^2+xh=1+x^2$

Answer (score 1):

1. For every $a, h\ne 0$ we have
   \begin{eqnarray}
   \dfrac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}&=&\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{a+h}-\sqrt[3]{a}}{h}=\dfrac{(\sqrt[3]{a+h}-\sqrt[3]{a})[(\sqrt[3]{a+h})^2+\sqrt[3]{a}\sqrt[3]{a+h}+(\sqrt[3]{a})^2]}{h[(\sqrt[3]{a+h})^2+\sqrt[3]{a}\sqrt[3]{a+h}+(\sqrt[3]{a})^2]}\\
   &=&\dfrac{(\sqrt[3]{a+h})^3-(\sqrt[3]{a})^3}{h[(\sqrt[3]{a+h})^2+\sqrt[3]{a}\sqrt[3]{a+h}+(\sqrt[3]{a})^2]}\\
   &=&\dfrac{a+h-a}{h[(\sqrt[3]{a+h})^2+\sqrt[3]{a}\sqrt[3]{a+h}+(\sqrt[3]{a})^2]}\\
   &=&\dfrac{h}{h[(\sqrt[3]{a+h})^2+\sqrt[3]{a}\sqrt[3]{a+h}+(\sqrt[3]{a})^2]}\\
   &=&\dfrac{1}{(\sqrt[3]{a+h})^2+\sqrt[3]{a}\sqrt[3]{a+h}+(\sqrt[3]{a})^2}\\
   \end{eqnarray}
   Taking the limit as $h$ goes to zero, we get
   \begin{eqnarray}
   \lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{1}{(\sqrt[3]{a+h})^2+\sqrt[3]{a}\sqrt[3]{a+h}+(\sqrt[3]{a})^2}=\dfrac{1}{3\sqrt[3]{a^2}}
   \end{eqnarray}
   Hence
   $$
   f'(a)=\dfrac{1}{3\sqrt[3]{a^2}}
   $$
2. For every $h\ne 0$ we have
   $$
   \dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\dfrac{f(x)+f(h)+x^2h+xh^2-f(x)}{h}=\dfrac{f(h)}{h}+x^2+xh
   $$
   Taking the limit, we get
   $$
   \lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=
   \lim_{h\to0}\left[\dfrac{f(h)}{h}+x^2+xh\right]=1+x^2
   $$
   Hence
   $$
   f'(x)=1+x^2
   $$